# iOS-SceneKitのジオメトリーの回転を行いたい

Tags: swift, ios

画像のようなCylinderのジオメトリ(x軸方向に22度傾いている)を画像でいうと緑色の線の軸を中心に回転させたいのですがやり方がわかりません。
ご教授いただけると助かります。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 0):

SCNNode を回転させる場合 SCNAction.rotateBy(x:y:z:duration:) を使います。
SCNNode の runAction() に回転させる SCNAction を渡してアクションを実行します。

```
// シーンの取得
let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/main.scn")!

// cylinder node の取得
let cylinder = scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "cylinder", recursively: true)!

// cylinder を y 軸に永遠に回転させる
cylinder.runAction(SCNAction.repeatForever(SCNAction.rotateBy(x: 0, y: 2, z: 0, duration: 1)))
```